# Making a simple JavaScript Slider, how would I add a description to my images?

Tags: javascript

I am starting out with JavaScript and I really love using it.  I apologize for being a noob, but I have alot of passion for this.   Here is my code below.  I would like to have a description with my simple slider.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

*note* I know jQuery can achieve better results, but first I want to master normal javascript.

```
   var featureImg = document.getElementById("photoSlider");

    var ImgArray = ["image1.png" , "image2.png" , "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png"];
    var index = 0;

    function newImage() {
        featureImg.setAttribute("src", ImgArray[index]);
        index++;

        if (index >= ImgArray.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(newImage, 2000);
```

Comment: How do you want the description to be displayed?

Comment: Preferably below the image itself.  Doesn't need any transitions or anything, just text that goes with the images probably in a div tag below the images referenced with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array of objects and do something like,

**HTML**

```
<img id="photoSlider"></img>
<div id="photoDescription"></div>
```

**js**

```
var featureImg = document.getElementById("photoSlider");
var imgDescription = document.getElementById("photoDescription");

    var ImgArray = [{src:"http://placehold.it/140x101",desc:"description 1"},
 {src:"http://placehold.it/140x102",desc:"description 2"} ,
 {src:"http://placehold.it/140x103",desc:"description 3"}, 
{src:"http://placehold.it/140x104",desc:"description 4"}, 
{src:"http://placehold.it/140x105",desc:"description 5"}];
    var index = 0;

    function newImage() {
        featureImg.setAttribute("src", ImgArray[index].src);
        imgDescription.innerHTML= ImgArray[index].desc;
        index++;

        if (index >= ImgArray.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(newImage, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5LtZ/2/

Comment: You might want to edit the description in your array. It makes it difficult to tell the image/description is changing

Comment: Works Good, appreciate it.  I didn't even know about placehold.it, I will certainly remember that for any future projects.

Answer (score 0):

only update

```
featureImg.src = ImgArray[Index];
```